# Trying to script a matrix multiplication experiment

Tags: c, matrix, scripting

So I am tasked with scripting a program that multiplies random matrices between size 50 and 3000, and I have hit a snag. I am unsure of the best way to change the size while the script is running. I could manually do it but that would take hours of sitting in front of the computer, and I feel like there is a simple way that I am missing. I am aware that if I define these matrices within main, anything over about 800 will cause the proverbial stack overflow, which is why I have placed them outside of main. Unfortunately, now I cannot simply pass N as argv[1]. My question is this: is it possible to be able to script something along these lines:

```
./matrix 50  
./matrix 150  
./matrix 200
```

et cetera
and if so, how?

```
#include <foo>
#define N 1000


int A[N][N];
int B[N][N];
int result[N][N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//so on
```

thank you in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Use `malloc()` to create your arrays on the heap where they belong.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the size while running?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage ah malloc, forgot about that one

Comment: @Pablo as in, creating a script that will just run the same program for matrices sizes 50, 100, 150 ... 2950, 3000

Comment: I thought you wanted to change the size of a already constructed matrix. Then `malloc` is the way to go.

Comment: malloc it is, thanks fellas

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension `n` is passed to the program as an argument, the
`malloc`/`calloc` is a good option. I'd do something like this:

```
int **matrix_create(size_t dim)
{
    int **matrix = calloc(dim, sizeof *matrix);

    if(matrix == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = calloc(dim, sizeof *matrix[i]);
        if(matrix[i] == NULL)
        {
            matrix_free(matrix, dim);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

void matrix_free(int **matrix, size_t dim)
{
    if(matrix == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        free(matrix[i]);

    free(matrix);
}
```

Then you can create the matrix from `main` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dim\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // just an example of how to convert,
    // you could also use strtol
    size_t dim = atoi(argv[i]);

    int **matrix_a = matrix_create(dim);
    if(matrix_a == NULL)
        return 1;

    int **matrix_b = matrix_create(dim);
    if(matrix_b == NULL)
    {
        matrix_free(matrix_a);
        return 1;
    }

    do_something_with(matrix_a, matrix_b, dim);


    matrix_free(matrix_a);
    matrix_free(matrix_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I used `calloc` instead of `malloc`, because `calloc` has the benefit
to set 0 to the allocated memory. It's great for initializing and error
handling, because `free(NULL)` is allowed, so as you see when allocating memory
for the `matrix[i]` rows, if something goes wrong, I can safely use
`matrix_free` on the whole matrix.